# GNU GSL sorting two vectors

Tags: c, sorting, vector, gsl

I have recently been using GNU GSL to vector computations - and so far, it has been awesome!
Now, however, I would like to sort two vectors (sorting one vector and then sorting the other vector based on the former). Luckily, GNU GSL seems to have a function for this, as quoted:

`Function: void gsl_sort_vector2 (gsl_vector * v1, gsl_vector * v2)
This function sorts the elements of the vector v1 into ascending numerical order, while making the same rearrangement of the vector v2.`

..which is exactly what I wanted. However, when I try to implement this, I keep getting undefined error on `gsl_sort_vector2`. So, my `skeletal` code looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sort_vector.h>

< do some vector related stuff here >

/* +++ This works completely fine ++++ */
/* gsl_sort_vector (res); */

/* +++ This gives the undefined error ++++ */
gsl_sort_vector2 (res, id);
```

where `res` and `id` are GSL vectors.

On compiling, the error is simply:

`undefined reference to gsl_sort_vector2 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I was wondering what could I be doing wrong - but so far been very unsuccessful on this.
Would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: the gnu gnu scientific library?

Comment: Yes Steve, that's right: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: What does your compile command look like? You are passing `-Wall` and clearing all warnings? What version of `gcc` and `gsl` are you using? What are your vectors? Have you included the appropriate type sort header? (e.g.: `gsl_sort_vector_float.h`)

Comment: `gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -I ..` is what I am using. I do not think this is an issue. My vectors are simple vectors - floats to be specific. As I have mentioned, `gsl_sort_vector` works absolutely fine - which means I have the right headers. gcc==4.7.2; gsl==1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GSL trunk page](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/gsl/trunk/annotate/head:/NEWS) shows that `gsl_sort_vector2` was only added in version 1.16 (commit 4821). Then, you are probably using an old version of the library given that you state that all other vector operations works fine (meaning that there isn't a linking problem)

Comment: @Vinivius: I am using 1.9 version - so version I think is not the issue.

Comment: 1.9? That is a very old version.

Comment: Ah..your right!! For some reason, I chose 1.9 as the download version (presumably because it was the last - how dumb!) thanks so much again! Accepted your answer.